# Why there is a word "does" in the first sentence and no "does" in the second?

Tags: interrogatives, do-support, subject-auxiliary-inversion

1. What time does the plane arrive tomorrow?
2. Where the plane arrives?

Or one of this sentences is incorrect? (I'm not english-speaking person).

Answer (score 2):

*Where the plane arrives?* is incorrect: as a question this also requires [subject-auxiliary-inversion](/questions/tagged/subject-auxiliary-inversion). You want to say

> Where does the plane arrive?

However, *where the plane arrives* is acceptable as a subordinate relative clause; this does not employ subject-auxiliary inversion:

> Gate 17, where the plane arrives, is on the West Concourse.
>   Where the plane arrives will depend on the weather.
>   I don't know where the plane arrives

ADDED:
Edwin Ashworth points out that a relative like *Where the plane arrives* may actually act as either a canonical question or a declarative question in a context where it is understood as a fragment—the remainder of a full sentence from which readily inferrable matter has been omitted as superfluous:

> CANONICAL QUESTION:
>   **A:** Go right on down to Gate 17.
>   **B:** <s>Is that</s> where the plane arrives?
>
> DECLARATIVE QUESTION:
>   **A:** Go right on down to Gate 17.
>   **B:** <s>And that is</s> where the plane arrives?

Note however that neither of these expressly asks the hearer to name the location, as *Where does the plane arrive?* does—they ask the hearer to confirm or deny your understanding that the plane arrives at Gate 17.

Comment: It may be used informally as a fragment: _"Will that be Runway 2?" ... _"Where the plane arrives?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good point--I've added that.

Comment: A declarative question would be 'The plane arrives at Gate 17?' This is a fragment. It could be based on either 'And that is [the gate] where the plane arrives?' _or_  'Is that [the gate] where the plane arrives?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think I said that--it is a fragment acting as a canonical/declarative question.

Comment: I'm guessing OP's ***where*** in the second example was effectively a "typo" for ***when***. But presumably that's also a subordinate relative clause - *I'll call you **when** the plane arrives.*